# Implementing a common interface from through different classes Java

Tags: java, database, object, interface

I have the method here to add users to a database, based on given arguments (username, password, etc...)

```
public boolean addUser(String username, String password, 
    String f_name, String l_name, String email) 
{
    try 
    {
        pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users VALUES (user_id_increment.nextval,?,?,?,?)");
        //do stuff...
```

And one here to add `User` objects to an `ArrayList`

```
public boolean addUser(User username)
{
    if(users.contains(username))
        //do stuff...
```

However, I'm trying to implement both cases through a common interface:

```
public interface Admin_DAO {

    public void addUser();
    //other methods...
```

I'm not sure how I could do this so that both classes can implement the same interface, given that they require different arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a `User` and pass it in. Or use method overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Admin DAO to accept a *User* data object to accommodate any future changes to the number of arguments that you need to pass without affecting the *public* interface.

```
public interface AdminDAO {
    public boolean addUser(User user);
}
```

Then implement this method as an overload in your User DAO. I also suggest that you store or pass your passwords around as `char[]` to prevent *interning* (addition into the Java string pool).

```
public class UserDAO implements AdminDAO {

    public boolean addUser(User user) {
        return addUser (user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                        user.getFName(), user.getLName(), user.getEmail());
    }

    public boolean addUser( 
        String username, char[] password,
        String f_name, String l_name, String email) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

***EDIT :** (extending an interface in respone to OP's comments below)*

```
public interface IUser {
    public boolean addUser(User user);
}

public interface AdminDAO extends IUser {
    // other DAO methods
}

public class UserDAO implements AdminDAO {
    // ...
}

public class UserUtil implements IUser {

    public boolean addUser(User user) {
        return addUser (user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                        user.getFName(), user.getLName(), user.getEmail());
    }

    public boolean addUser( 
        String username, char[] password,
        String f_name, String l_name, String email) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like it would work great, but I can't have the user implementing all of AdminDAO's methods, such as ban and unban a user. The user should only be able to add himself (register).

Comment: What you could do here then is to factor out the common methods into a different interface, say IUser and have your AdminDAO interface extend it without needing to repeat the same method declarations. Now User would only implement IUser and the DAO would implement the extended AdminDAO.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't implement an interface method with multiple different signatures.**

Now that I've got that out of the way, let me clarify. An interface includes method signatures. You cannot implement that interface by changing the method signatures, because that fundamentally changes how Java sees the method. Java considers two methods with different signatures to be just as different as if they had different names. So you could write a class with two different `addUser` methods, but only one of them will override the method from the interface.

**If your methods require totally different information, they probably shouldn't be implementing the same interface.** However, if they require essentially the same information but in a different format, then you should write an interface that accepts a common format for that information, and then they can both implement it. So for instance, if it turns out that a `User` looks basically like this:

```
public User(String username, String password, String f_name, String l_name, String email) {
}
```

Then you can make your interface accept `User` objects.

```
public interface Admin_DAO {
    public void addUser(User u);
}
```

And then you can implement that as needed in your different classes.

Comment: My answer compliments yours nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the arguments in an interface.

```
public interface IUser{
    String getName();
    String getPassword();
    //etc
}
```

Then have your Admin_DAO accept IUsers.

```
public interface Admin_DAO{
    void addUser(IUser user);
    boolean contains(IUser user);
}
```

This allows abstraction of Admin_DAO implementation details.  It could be a database, or just an in memory datastructure.  Having it accept data wrapped in an interface lets you pass in the same type of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, there should be two classes. As the information used for both the method is same. You interface should look like this :

```
interface Admin_DAO{

public void addUser(User user);

}
```

And you should have two separate classes implementing this interface:

```
class AddUserToList implements Admin_DAO{
    public void addUser(User user){
      //add user to list
    }

class addUserToDB implements Admin_DAO{

   public void addUser(User user){
      //add user to list
    }
```

**Each class should actually serve one purpose.**

Answer (score 0):

Short answer **You cannot.**
Here are a couple of my favorite paragraphs from GoF Design Patterns book. The text below should clear any query you have. You may want to read it a couple of times.

> Every operation declared by an object specifies the operation's name,
>   the objects it takes as parameters,and the operation's return
>   value.This is known as the operation's signature.The set of all
>   signatures defined by an object's operations is called the interface
>   to the object. An object's interface characterizes the complete set of
>   requests that can be sent to the object. Any request that matches a
>   signature in the object's interface may be sent to the object.
>
> A type is a name used to denote a particular interface. We speak of an
>   object as having  the type "Window" if it accepts all requests for the
>   operations defined in the interface  named "Window." An object may
>   have many types, and widely different objects can  share a type.Part
>   of an object's interface may be characterized by one type, and other
>   parts by other types.Two objects of the same type need only share
>   parts of their  interfaces. Interfaces can contain other interfaces as
>   subsets. We say that a type is a subtype of another if its interface
>   contains the interface of its supertype. Often we speak of a subtype
>   inheriting the interface of its supertype.
>
> Interfaces are fundamental in object-oriented systems. Objects are
>   known only through their interfaces.There is no way to know any thing
>   about an object or to ask it to do anything without going through its
>   interface. An object's interface says nothing about its
>   implementation-different objects are free to implement requests
>   differently.